# PHP write file writes constants twice

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When I try to execute this really simple code

```
<?php
  $myfile = fopen("db.txt", "at") or die ("Unable to open file!");
  $text = $_GET["name"];
  $text .="\n";
  echo $text;

  fwrite($myfile, $text);
  fwrite($myfile, "abc\n");
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

My file turns into something like that

```
coolname
abc
abc
```

Twice the "abc\n" string. I promised, my code is only that few lines.

The request is just `http://localhost:8080/helloworld.php?name=coolname`

But if I just only use this...

```
  fwrite($myfile, $_GET["name"]);
```

all works fine but I want a ending line.

Can someone explain me why it happens?

Im using the PHP AppEngine SDK. (9 years since my last PHP experience)

**Solution:**

The problem is that when I open this URL in a browser it is processed twice doing something weird, I don't know why, but my app just need to be called from a custom app so, from my app, this code is executed just once. Is not a real solution, the bug is still there, but it does not affect my workflow.

Comment: What is the initial content of your file, the content of `$_GET['name']` and the output when it "all works fine" ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/helloworld.php?name=coolname

And the output just 'coolname' when don't write anything else. (without spaces or endlines or simple chars or whatever)

Comment: What if you try : `fwrite($myfile, $text . "abc\n");` ?

Comment: A wreider thing:

`coolname\nabc\n\nabc\n`


Why this two "\n" in the middle? haha

Comment: You open the file with "a", meaning you'll append to the end of the already-existing contents.

Comment: But the file is empty before I write something, thats why I think that probably it is a GAE's bug.

Comment: Is it possible that the code is executed twice because GAE decides by itself? How can I prevent this behavior? I want to apply this solution to an insert in a db.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `fwrite($myfile, "abc\n");` which writes abc. is you $_GET also contains abc
otherwise it is writing fine.

```
<?php 

  $myfile = fopen("YourFile.txt", "at") or die ("Unable to open file!");
  $text = 'hello guys';
  $text .="\n";
  echo $text;

  fwrite($myfile, $text);
  fwrite($myfile, "abc\n");
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: No, my $_GET not contains the "abc\n" string, that's why I'm loosing.

The request is this
http://localhost:8080/helloworld.php?name=coolname

Comment: after fwrite($myfile, $text); close the file then again open then use fwrite($myfile, "abc\n"); see what happens.

Comment: A wreider thing (exactly the same that the Cleément's suggestion):  `coolname\nabc\n\nabc\n` Two "\n" in the middle

Comment: open your file in mode=a i.e.fopen("YourFile.txt", "a") and try.

Comment: Same :( thanks for your effort
Probably a bug of the AppEngine SDK?